# Getting error while fetching String using getString from SharedPreference package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

This is the scenario: I want to check whether any json data I have saved before , if not I want to save some data using setString, else I want to print it.
This is my sharedPreference class

```
class DataSharedPreference {
  static const dataKey = 'data_key';

  static void saveData(String data) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(dataKey, jsonEncode(data));
  }

  static Future<String> getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return jsonDecode(prefs.getString(dataKey));
  }

  static void removeData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(dataKey);
  }
}
```

This is my method

```
void check() async {
String data;
      try {
        await UserDataSharedPreference.getData().then((value) async {
          if (value != null) {
            data = value;
            print(data);
          } else {
            UserDataSharedPreference.saveData('myData');
          }

          if(data.isNotEmpty) {
            print('Achieved');
          } else {
            print('failed');
          }

        });
      } catch (e) {
        print('Catch from check(){} : $e');
      }
    }
```

This is my error

```
I/flutter ( 7730): Catch from check(){} : NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 7730): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 7730): Tried calling: length
```

This error only occurs when i try to fetch data using getString before actually implementing it using setString.How to avoid this?

This is the simplified version of what I want at the end.

1. Check
2. if hasData: print
3. else : Save

Answer (score 0):

If your **value** is **null** you call saveData() but your **data** on line 2 is still not set, this means **null**. If you check `data.isNotEmpty` an error occurs, since **data** is **null**

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now, How to check that I have saved anything or not?

Comment: I want to check whether i have saved anything or not before actually saving it in my sharedPreserence, how to achieve this?

Comment: Your first if else is enough to check if you have saved something. If value is null, then you didn't save anything. Else you saved something.

Comment: By the way either use await or then. Don't use both at the same time, otherwise omit the await, since it is unnecessary.

Comment: Exactly the problem is here I think. I was not saving any data to the shared Preference.....before saving, I am using getString here. This is were problem occurs and the then((value)=>); is not helping.

Comment: You could do something like that. var data = await UserDataSharedPreference.getData(); if(data ==null) {not saved} else { saved}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228221/discussion-between-quoci-and-arud).